# How to change order of array dimensions

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

How do I reorder the dimensions of an n dimensional array.  For example, if I have a three dimensional array of sales data, where the first dimension represents the Date, the second dimension is the Store, and the third dimension is Department.  How do I transform the array so that the first dimension is Store, the second is Department, and the third is Date.  This is just an example.  I am hoping for a general solution.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The function for doing that is `aperm`, from the base package. It is a generalization of the transpose `t()` function to multidimensional arrays. For your example, you would call it as follows:

```
new.data <- aperm(old.data, c(2,3,1))
```