# How to designate "binding method" in apply

Tags: r

Say, I have a matrix `m` with 2 rows and 3 columns, together with a function which takes in an argument of numeric type and return a vector. For example,

```
f <- function(x){
    rep(x,4)
}
```

If I use

```
 t <- apply(m, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = f)
```

I will get a tensor `t` with `dim(t) == c(4,2,3)`. But what I want is a tensor `t` with `dim(t) == c(2,3,4)`. How can I do this conveniently? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, tensors are called arrays in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aperm`, a generalized transposition:

```
tt <- <- apply(m, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = f)
aperm(tt, c(2,3,1))
```

See here: [How to change order of array dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679131/how-to-change-order-of-array-dimensions)