# How swap two column in a multiarray in R

Tags: r

I have a multidimensional array in R, with 3 dimensions like: dim(my.array)= 144,12,73

I just wanted to change the 2 and 3 column to get a new array:[144,73,12]

Is that possible? Because I tried with something like that:
   my.array = my.array[c(144,73,12),,]
but I know that is wrong...I don't know if there is a straightforward way to do it.

I will appreciate any idea!

Thanks

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679131/how-to-change-order-of-array-dimensions)

Comment: Start with a small example (2x3x4) and try things.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [the `aperm` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/aperm.html):

```
x <- array(1:(144*12*73), dim=c(144,12,73))
dim(x)
# [1] 144  12  73
dim(aperm(x, c(1,3,2)))
# [1] 144  73  12
```