# R: create an array of matrices from a list

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix

I am trying to create an array from matrices. The matrices are all of identical dimensions (NxN). I have every matrix in a single csv file without header. Data are tab delimited. 
In other threads it was suggested to do it as follows:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
named.list <- lapply(temp, read.csv,header=FALSE, sep = "")
arr <- abind(named.list)
```

However, this does not create what I want. This creates a 2-dimenaional Nx(N*k) data frame (where N = columns/rows and k = number of matrices). 
So in my case I have 5 matrices, 40 columns and 40 rows each. Using abind creates a [1:40, 1:200] data frame.

```
> str(arr)
 int [1:40, 1:200] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:200] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
```

What I want is a [1:40, 1:40, 1:5] three-dimensional array of matrices:

```
> str(z)
 int [1:40, 1:40, 1:5] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I think my fundamental problem is that I cannot manage to convert the list of data frames in named.list to a list of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

r <- simplify2array(temp)
```

However, the resulting array had dimensions `[nrow, ncol, n]` where the first two elements are matrix dimensions and the last is the number of matrices stored in r. My specific analysis required `[n, nrow, ncol]` to achieve this change I used the `aperm` function as follows `r <- aperm(r, c(3,1,2))` based on this answer [function from base package that is a generalization of the transpose t() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679131/how-to-change-order-of-array-dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, the "abind" got me close. The following line was missing:

```
arr2<-array(arr,dim= c(40,40,5))
```

This gives me:

```
str(arr2)
 int [1:40, 1:40, 1:5] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

abind is the way to go. If rbindlist was used beforehand, the structure of the individual data sets gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
library(data.table)
arr <- rbindlist(named.list ,use.names = T,fill = T);
```