# R: Cast multiple raster stacks into 4D array

Tags: arrays, r, keras, raster

**context:**
I have hundreds of raster stacks with the same number of layers per stack. Each stack covers a different square geographic tile of a larger study area. Each stack can have one or many layers; these I am equating to image channels. Therefore each stack is can be seen as a 3D array of (x,y,c). I would like to take the *z* number of raster stacks and cast them as a 4D array of (z,x,y,c). The purpose of which is to format these data for training a network in Keras that expects "channel-last" (z,x,y,c) arrays.

**Question:**
How do I represent a raster stack as a multichannel image and cast to a 4D array of shape (z,x,y,c)?

**Reprex:**

```
library(raster)
## three layers/channels for tile #1
x1_1 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x1_1[] <- c(11:14)
x1_2 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x1_2[] <- c(15:18)
x1_3 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x1_3[] <- c(19:22)
# three layers/channels for tile #2
x2_1 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x2_1[] <- c(21:24)
x2_2 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x2_2[] <- c(25:28)
x2_3 <- raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
x2_3[] <- c(29:32)
# stack channels from each tile
x1 <- stack(x1_1,x1_2,x1_3)
x2 <- stack(x2_1,x2_2,x2_3)
dim(x1) # (2,2,3)
# cast vectors of each 
array(c(as.vector(x1),as.vector(x2)),c(2,2,2,3))
```

this casts the stacks into a 4D array, but not in the correct order.

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   13
[2,]   12   14

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   17
[2,]   16   18

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   19   21
[2,]   20   22

...
```

The x and y are transposed and the order is ordered by the 4th (channel) dimension of each stack. The desired ordering is to have the first dimension as the number of raster stacks/tiles *z*,then x, y, and finally the channels for each raster (1 through 3 in this case). The print order in R would be (z,x,y,c) enumerated as (1,2,2,1);(1,2,2,2);(1,2,2,3);(2,2,2,1);(2,2,2,2);(2,2,2,3)

I realize I am not explaining the question too well as I have not dealt with multi-dimensional arrays too much in the past. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your notion of "the correct order".

Comment: great questions; clarification added to end of post. Thanks!

Comment: Still unclear. That array has 24 elements and you are asking to index only 6 of them. Post a complete answer showing what you think is the desired display order and arrangement.

Comment: apologies for lack of clarity. The dim of array at the end of my example is (2,2,2,3) as (x,y,z,c), I desire (z,x,y,c). unfortunately that would also be dim == (2,2,2,3) due to me limiting the example to two raster stacks. If that was 10 raster stacks, it would be dim == (10,2,2,3). thanks!

Comment: If you happen to have keras package for R, you can load the cifar10 data from the example below and see the desired result; dim(x_train) == (50000,32,32,3) or (number of images, x pixels, y pixels, RGB channels) https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/cifar10_cnn.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need your output to be an array or a raster?  if an array, the `aperm` function is what you need ([ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679131/how-to-change-order-of-array-dimensions)):

```
arr <- array(c(as.vector(x1),as.vector(x2)),c(2,2,2,3))
aperm(arr, c(3,1,2,4))
```