# R equivalent to permuting array dimensions permute(A, dimorder) in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, cell-array, permute

I am looking for an equivalent of `permute(A,dimorder)` from Matlab, in order to convert some Matlab code to R.
A loop entails a line that looks something like this:

```
x = permute(a{i}(b(i,ii),:,:,:,:,:),[2 3 4 5 6 1])
```

The cell array structure e.g. `a{1}(1,:,:,:,:,:)` results in selecting the first row of matrices within the cell array `a{}`. `[2 3 4 5 6 1]` in `permute()` refers to the `dimorder`.
The documentation for the matlab function `permute()` including example output can be found here:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html

There are several functions in R referring to permutation in some way or another, but non of them seemed to be what I am looking for, though I may have gotten something wrong.

Comment: For base R, `aperm`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679131/how-to-change-order-of-array-dimensions

Comment: @jblood94 Unfortunatly I do not get equivalent results to the matlab code if I use ``aperm(a[[i]] [b[i,ii],], c(2,3,4,5,6,1))``.  With abind I do not know how to include the part ``[2 3 4 5 6 1]``.

Comment: Interesting. The functions are equivalent as far as I can tell. Can you put together a reproducible example?

Comment: @jbloo94 I added some matlab code to my question that delivers reproducable results. It is a Matlab script I am converting (cut out most of the comments, so it may look a little chaotic, relevant line (loop) is in the lower part).

Comment: Can you add your R attempt?

Comment: @jblood94 Added my R attempt as well. Relevant lines again in the lower part.

Comment: According to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/R-and-octave.txt  `permute(a,[2 1 3])` and R's `aperm(a,c(2,1,3))` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I successfully replicated the MATLAB script in R. I don't think you actually need an equivalent for `permute`. In the MATLAB script, `permute` appears to be simply dropping excess dimensions. R does that by default unless you specify `drop = FALSE` when you subset an array, e.g.,

```
lnA[[tau, modal]] <- a[[modal]][outcomes[modal, tau],,,drop = FALSE]
```

If I add `lnA = cell(T, NumModalities);` to the MATLAB script before your final `for` loop and then modify the inside of the loop to be

```
lnA{tau, modal} = permute(a{modal}(outcomes(modal,tau),:,:,:,:,:),[2 3 4 5 6 1]);
```

Then I get the same array of matrices in `lnA` for both the MATLAB and R implementations.

In R, I use an array of lists as the equivalent of a MATLAB 2+ dimension cell array:

```
lnA1 = cell(T, 1); # MATLAB
lnA1 <- vector("list", Time) # R    
lnA2 = cell(T, NumModalities); # MATLAB
lnA2 <- array(vector("list", Time*NumModalities), c(Time, NumModalities)) # R
lnA2 <- matrix(vector("list", Time*NumModalities), Time) # R
lnA3 = cell(T, NumModalities, 2); # MATLAB
lnA3 <- array(vector("list", Time*NumModalities*2), c(Time, NumModalities, 2)) # R
```

Here's the implementation:

```
nat_log <- function (x) { # necessary as log(0) not defined...
  x <- log(x + exp(-16))
}

# Set up a list for D and A
D <- list(c(1, 0),       # (left better, right better)
          c(1, 0, 0, 0)) #(start, hint, choose-left, choose-right)
A <- c(rep(list(array(0, c(3, 2, 4))), 2), list(array(0, c(4, 2, 4))))

Ns <- lengths(D) # number of states in each state factor (2 and 4)
A[[1]][,,1:Ns[2]] <- matrix(c(1,1,  # No Hint
                              0,0,  # Machine-Left Hint
                              0,0), # Machine-Right Hint
                      ncol = 2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

pHA <- 1
A[[1]][,,2] <- matrix(c(0,       0,       # No Hint
                        pHA,     1 - pHA, # Machine-Left Hint
                        1 - pHA, pHA),    # Machine-Right Hint
                      nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

A[[2]][,,1:2] <- matrix(c(1, 1,   # Null
                          0, 0,   # Loss
                          0, 0),  # Win
                        ncol = 2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

pWin <- 0.8
A[[2]][,,3] <- matrix(c(0,        0,         # Null        
                        1 - pWin, pWin,      # Loss
                        pWin,     1 - pWin), # Win
                      ncol = 2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

A[[2]][,,4] <- matrix(c(0,        0,        # Null        
                        pWin,     1 - pWin, # Loss
                        1 - pWin, pWin),    # Win
                      ncol = 2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

for (i in 1:Ns[2]) {
  A[[3]][i,,i] <- c(1,1)
}

# Set up a list of matrices:
a <- lapply(1:3, function(i) A[[i]]*200)
a[[1]][,,2] <- matrix(c(0,    0,     # No Hint
                        0.25, 0.25,  # Machine-Left Hint
                        0.25, 0.25), # Machine-Right Hint
                      nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

outcomes <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1,
                     1, 1, 2,
                     1, 2, 4),
                   ncol = 3, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

NumModalities <- length(a)       # number of outcome factors
Time <- 3L
lnA <- array(vector("list", Time*NumModalities), c(Time, NumModalities))

for (tau in 1:Time){
  for (modal in 1:NumModalities){
    lnA[[tau, modal]] <- a[[modal]][outcomes[modal, tau],,]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked! I implemented this loop to translate my "a" matrix list into the array list: ```a1 <- c(rep(list(array(0, c(3, 2, 4))), 2), list(array(0, c(4, 2, 4))))
for (i in 1:ncol(A)){
  for (ii in 1:nrow(A)){
    a1[[ii]][,,i] = a[[ii,i]] 
  }
}  ``` Called it a1 for differentiating purpose to "a"...